# Permission issues using sickrage and transmission

Tags: hard-drive, permissions

I've setup transmission and sickrage to automattically download series. This went well, however when Sickrage tries to move the files, it gets stuck and the logs say: `2016-07-25 16:10:13 POSTPROCESSER :: Processing failed for /mnt/usbstorage/downloads/complete/***.mkv: File is locked for reading/writing`

I've checked all permissions of files and folders and I cant get my head around the problem. Also I've currently set Transmission to stop the torrent after it completes. Did I overlook something? I'm running Raspbian Jessie

Permissions of all files and folders:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 root                root      4096       mrt  8 10:02 /mnt
drwxr-xr-x   7 root                root      4096       jul 21 23:40 /mnt/usbstorage

drwxrwxr-x   4 root                downloads 4096       jul 21 23:00 /mnt/usbstorage/downloads
drwxrwsr-x  34 root                downloads 4096       jul 25 13:07 /mnt/usbstorage/downloads/complete
-rwxr-xr-x   1 debian-transmission downloads 2104212313 jul 25 13:07 /mnt/usbstorage/downloads/complete/***.mkv

drwxrwxr-x   8 root                downloads 4096       jul 25 11:32 /mnt/usbstorage/series
drwxrwxr-x   4 sickrage            sickrage  4096       jul 23 06:52 /mnt/usbstorage/series/***
```

Users of downloads:

```
$ grep downloads /etc/group
downloads:x:120:debian-transmission,sickrage
```

Comment: File *locking* probably doesn't (because it shouldn't) refer to file *permissions*. More likely, it is about a system of voluntary locking (see `man flock` for a hint) sometimes used by multi-process applications for synchronization (e.g., so they don't end up trying to read meaningful information from a file while that information is being changed).  Notice it says *locked for reading/writing*, i.e., this file is not available to read or write, which is what you would want to do if you were writing to it, until you were finished. It looks like that synchronization is flawed in this case...

Comment: Sounds like standard torrent client behaviour. When the file's completed it's normally acting as a seed for other users (i.e. being read from), hence the file is locked/can't be moved. I haven't touched Transmission before, but you're likely to need to remove it from the torrent queue before moving the file.

Comment: This looks relevant: https://gist.github.com/bulljit/791609 . Interestingly, they're moving the files *first* using transmission-remote's '-move' flag, and *then* removing them from the torrent queue using the '-remove' flag.

Comment: Thanks for all comments! I've read into `flock` and `lsof`. However when I run `$ sudo lsof | grep downloads` I do not see the files that sickrage is complaining about. The script from @goobering did not help either unfortunately.